# Split and store all the last elements into an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to store the string values retrieved into an array or list and then sort them.I have tried many ways to store them in the said manner.But nothing is helpful. can someone please help me in this regard.

```
List<WebElement> list = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(expression));
int listcount = list.size();    
List optionsList = null;
String options[] = new String[listcount];

for (int i=1; i<=listcount; i++) {                     
    options[i-1] = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression")).getText();
    //contains three words eg: Test Engineer Madhu               
    String[] expectedOptions = options[i-1].split(" ");
    //splitting based on the space           
    String lastName =expectedOptions[expectedOptions.length-1]; 
    //taking the lastName.
    List<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
       strArray.add(lastName);        
    }
    optionsList = Arrays.asList(lastName);
}          
System.out.println(optionsList);
//This always results in last option's last name eg: [Madhu]
}
```

Now, I want all the last Names to be stored in an array to verify if they are in sorted order or not.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I tried the below code.But it is always storing only the last retrieved option's last name.                                                                                                  List<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
             strArray.add(lastName);
                           
            }

Comment: Instead of `options[i-1] = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression")).getText();` try `options[i-1] = list.get(i-1).getText();`

Comment: There is no problem with the options[i-1].Rather, failing to store the retrieved last Name into the list.

Comment: have you debug your code and checked whether the array `expectedOptions` is getting populated correctly

Comment: expected options contains the split Names.So, am just retrieving the lastName.It's retrieving correctly.

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified code to get all the last names in a array

```
List<WebElement> list = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(expression));
int listcount = list.size();    
List optionsList = null;
String options[] = new String[listcount];

for (int i=1; i<=listcount; i++) 
{                     
    options[i-1] = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression")).getText();
    //contains three words eg: Test Engineer Madhu               
    String[] expectedOptions = options[i-1].split(" ");
    //splitting based on the space           
    // I hope the next line gives you the correct lastName
    String lastName =expectedOptions[expectedOptions.length-1]; 
    // lets store the last name in the array
    options[i-1] = lastName;        
 }         
 optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);
 // Iterate through the list to see all last names.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like:

```
for (int i=1; i<=listcount; i++) {  
        //contains three words eg: Test Engineer Madhu               
        String[] expectedOptions = options[i-1].split(" ");
        //splitting based on the space           
        String lastName =expectedOptions[expectedOptions.length-1]; 
        //taking the lastName.
        options[i - 1] = lastName;
    }
    optionsList = Arrays.asList(options); 
    System.out.println(optionsList);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, Harbeer also provided the same solution. Thanks for your help.